# Why Google provides JSON, but i can't use them

Tags: jquery, api, xss

Google provides json format of api for java and others developers, not for jQuery user's? I can't create a cross domain queries for Google's json from my javascript (Same Origin Policy)? And if I can't use proxy, it means that google api not for me?

Comment: Which specific Google APIs are you talking about?

Comment: There is an official JavaScript library that will work in JQuery (and any JavaScript in the browser). If you have more specific questions please ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to ask about a specific Google API to get specifics in an answer.  Many can be used cross-origin with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or can be accessed with their [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/services).

Comment: Thanks for answer! I'm about Google Map API